# Why does yo office use port 3000?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, office-js, yo

According to [this article](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-using-any-editor), `yo office` defines the web-server port as 3000, in bsconfig.json.

Why 3000? Why not 80, or 8000, or 8080?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there would be any specific reason for port `3000`, but it is general behaviour to use port greater than 1024 to avoid sudo privilege dependency. I think that you can run the webserver on different port  by changing the port in `bsconfig.json`